How can I create a query that finds contour lines (linestring) that are not unified
How can I create a query that finds contour lines (linestring) that are not unified
Example:
In this image, the ideal would be just a red line, but there is a red and a white line, in this case the white one should be connected to the red one


Does this answer your question? How to select all groups of intersecting polygons from a single table using PostGIS

You can try to de-node/melt/dissolve/compact these lines with st_dump(st_linemerge(st_collect(geom))). Fully unified lines won't respond to this, coming out unchanged.
If you're showing an aftermath of a merge attempt, trying to track down which lines refused to dissolve and why, then I'd guess if you zoom all the way in or inspect vertex coords, you might observe any of these

they weren't unified because they don't really touch at all
one ends in the middle of the other one's last segment spawning a node
they run into each other having a whole common line rather than just one point
their final segments cross, again requiring a node in that location
lines are duplicated, making all their vertices intersection points requiring nodes, and what looks like a common end of two lines, is actually a common end of three or more lines, and effectively a crossing

Some of these can be resolved with st_snap().
You can also spot ones that lay in the middle of a sequence of lines by counting how many other lines they intersect. Your targets will only have 1 or 2 such neighbours:
select t1.id 
from your_table t1 
join your_table t2 
on t1.id<>t2.id 
and st_intersects(t1.geom,t2.geom)
group by t1.id having count(*) in (1,2)

This can get you a ton of false positives, so you might have to check only for the intersections of st_startpoint()/st_endpoint(), not the whole geom, which in turn won't get you the ones that run in a sequence but instead of meeting start-to-end, run into or through each other.
